# Is there a way to list animation available in Android OS at runtime?

Tags: android, android-animation

Long story short, I'm checking out the [framework animation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/grow_fade_in.xml?av=f) for some idea on my app. Switching and compiling every time waste a lot of time so I wonder if it's possible to iterate through android.R.anim some how? There seems to be only two types of resource in there so if I filter "_interpolator" out I should get all the available animation to check out.

Is this possible? Is there another option I can look at? Website with video of each resource?
Again, the only goal I want to achieve now is ability to quickly check the animation for UX/transition designing purpose.

Comment: you do know that you can create your own animations and you are really not bound to the provided animations , right?

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of that and it's what I'm intending to do. I just wanna get some idea of what sort of animation the platform is provided so i can make my behave not too contrasting with the rest of the OS.

Comment: i see. have you tried reflection ? seems like another app already does it for all kinds of built-in resources . it's called "android resources" : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.androidDrawables

Comment: Thanks, that's almost what I'm looking for. However, I'm wondering why's the available animation is different from the one in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/grow_fade_in.xml?av=f